# I am trying to write code that allows for a second attack animation to be played after the first if a key is pressed after the initial animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is the code I've written, I have got the first attack animation working using a trigger and some of the code written here but I'm struggling to find a way to check when the first animation has ended and then check whether a key has been pressed and if it has, to play the second animation. I've tried using `IEnumerator` to no avail and I'm a little stuck. I apologise if this is a novel issue, I'm relatively new to unity and C# and any help would be very much appreciated! (I know the code below is faulty, I'm just posting it as a reference so you know what I've already written and any possible solutions)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCombatBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
            Attack();
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("attack");
        while (animation.IsPlaying("MartialHeroAttack1"))
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
            animator.SetTrigger("attack2");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There is some logic missing in your description.  Can the button be pressed while the first animation is playing?  If not, is there a time limit where pressing the button after the first animation ends does not trigger the 2nd animation?  Side note, Attack needs to have the return type IEnumerator, and unless you are doing something at the end of frame related to this, best to use yield return null which continues execution on the following frame.

Comment: Keep in mind that the player can spam the "K" key multiple times so you need to handle that case too, otherwise it will break everything. You can try and create your "Attack" method as IEnumerator and then use the "StartCoroutine()" to call your Attack and simply every time player press key "K" check if coroutine is running or not. Also if you want to cancel everything and start again you can use the "StopCoroutine()" method.

Answer (score 0):

First what I see it that you use yield instructions in method which not return IEnumerator, If you want use coroutine, you should return IEnumerator and run it with help `StartCoroutine(nameof(Attack))`.
But I recommend to you in that case use **AnimationController** which give you more functions to control you animations.